# Regex match of string-numeric patterns

Tags: c#, regex

I have a couple of different string-numeric patterns that needs validation during user input.

They look like this

```
// Always a dash, always a comma
var variant1 = "0-5,99";

// Always a dash, never a comma, always integers
var variant2 = "10-20";
```

I was thinking of doing something like this but obviously it doesn't work :/

```
var reg1 = @"(\w{2})-(\w{2})";
var match = Regex.IsMatch(variant2 , reg1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var reg1 = @"^(?:\d+\-\d+,\d+)|(?:\d+\-\d+)$";
```

This looks for one of two groups, either matching "digit(s) dash digits(s) comma digit(s)"

```
^\d+\-\d+,\d+$
```

or matching "digit(s) dash digits(s)"

```
^\d+\-\d+$
```

and it uses `^` and `$` to force a "whole string" match.

Answer (score 0):

"[0-9]+-[0-9]+" ist at least one number, followed by the dash and at least one more number. (May be escape the middle "-", if it does not work)

Comment: This would still match 0-5.99 as true!